Can anyone explain the meaning of "as an old fisherman used to say when I was a boy not so very long ago, ..."
I read a novel, there is one sentence I cannot understand:

And he slapped the little bunny's back and gave a hop, skip and jump to one side, and then laughed some more, for he was as happy as a clam at high tide, as an old fisherman used to say when I was a boy not so very long ago, but just long enough to make me wish I were twenty years younger, just the samee.

My questions are:

Does “gave a hop, skip and jump to one side” mean ‘jump to one side’?
What is the meaning of "samee"?
What is the meaning of “as an old fisherman used to say when I was a boy not so very long ago, but just long enough to make me wish I were twenty years younger, just the samee”?
Is “as an old fisherman used to say..." the short form for "as happy as an old fisherman used to say..."?


Source and date?


No, he hopped, then skipped, then jumped to one side. 2. Samee is either a typo or an attempt to sound old-timey. 3. As an old fisherman used to say: "When I was a boy not so very long ago [a joke], but just long enough [30 years ago] to make me wish I were [at least] twenty years younger.” 4. No, not "as happy as an old fisherman used to say."


Basically, he's saying that he learned the aphorism "as happy as a clam at high tide" from the old fisherman.

"Blah", as X used to say means X used to say blah a lot. As=in the way.  Have you looked up "hop, skip, and jump"?

What novel? Cite your source. It's same: just the same. The e is a typo.

'Samee' is an OCR (Optical Character Recognition) error. Your book was written more than 100 years ago, and scanned and a program attempted to convert the images to text. The Project Gutenberg Project version  has the double-e in italics, confirming that it was a trouble spot. Maybe someone squashed a mosquito on that page.

The saying: [he was] as happy as a clam at high tide.

as X used to say is a standard formation, meaning that this is a thing which person X said a lot. It's a set phrase, and the when-clause expands on that. You've four different questions there, though, which you shouldn't do.

Answers to the numbered questions:

Yes, it means a jump to one side, in addition to a hop and a skip to that same side.

"Samee" isn't anything I've ever seen before.  Without further evidence, I'd assume it's a typographical error.

There was an old fisherman whom the narrator used to know back when the narrator was a boy.  That old fisherman frequently said that someone or something was as happy as a clam at high tide.  The narrator was a boy not so long ago.  However, the narrator still feels that he would like to be twenty years younger than he is now.

No.



Since the narrator would like to be twenty years younger, he's at least 30 or so. He is teasing to say a boy not so very long ago.

@YosefBaskin It's all relative.

A hop, skip and jump is a set colloquial phrase; the author may have used it as such, without clearly having in mind three distinct actions.
